# ajax no function after modify jquery script

Tags: jquery, ajax

i want to show some data from DB. and i'm use ajax to do that.
But something wrong is happen, the can't show after i have changed some jquery script in my page.

which part of following script that caused my page not show the result:

```
$("#model").change(function() {
             var barcode;
             barCode=$("#model").val();
             var data1 = $("#model").val(barCode.substr(0,barCode.length-8));
             var data2 = $("#serial").val(barCode.substr(barCode.length-8,8));
             var str= data1;
             var matches=str.match(/[TEJUG2]\D*D/i);
         $.ajax({
                  type:"post",
                  url:"process1.php",
                  data:"tversion="+matches+"&action=tunermatches",
                  cache:false,
                  async:false,
                  success: function(res){
                                 $('#value').replaceWith(
                                           "<div id='value'><h6>" + res + "</h6></div>"
                                           );
                                 }
                  });
```

---

what i want to do is after separate some data. the script will read data1 then do some filtering character from text value(use regex).

after match, ajax will send to DB then filtering data inside DB.
after that data will show inside page.

Comment: @klox , what do you get back from php , can you check with firebug if you are getting data?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'match'

Comment: there is some error here var matches=str.match(/[TEJUG2]\D*D/i); then

Comment: @gov: how to resolve that? sorry i'm not familiar in regex.

Comment: @klox, tell me what do you want to do there?? so that i can get you the right code

Comment: @klox i waited some 15 min , i am going to sleep , msg here once you are back , i can only look at tomorrow or someone else can answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing some strange things with your variables.

Initially, `barCode=$("#model").val();` looks reasonable, though you might want to combine it with the definition above.

Then you call `var data1 = $("#model").val(barCode.substr(0,barCode.length-8));`, so data1 is actually a jQuery object: http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2

So it looks like you are calling val(something) and expecting to get back the string, like if you'd called val(). What you probably want to do is say

`var data1 = $("#model").val(barCode.substr(0,barCode.length-8)).val();`

Because this will give you the actual value of what's in #model.

In addition, `matches` is an array, so you probably want to call

`data:"tversion="+matches.length+"&action=tunermatches",` instead (note the addition of the `.length` to `matches`).

Comment: i think my project still can work without change `matches` into `matches.length`.